# Creating border lines for sudoku puzzle

Tags: c

A few days back I have posted a question about generating the random boxes for this sudoku puzzle. Now I have difficulty with generating the border lines for it. It should look like this:
[image: Sudoku]

but I can't come up with the code to do that. The problem is that the rows 0 to 8 are taken up by the sudoku numbers, and I don't know how to put those '|' and '-' characters in between those numbers, and also on the borders I guess.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
    int column_random [81], row_random [81], n = 3, k, j, input, number;
    char check = '0';

    printf("Enter percentage of empty squares: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    srand ( time ( NULL) );

    number = (input *  81) / 100 ;

    for ( k = 0; k < number; k++ )
    {
        row_random [k] = rand () % 9 ;
        column_random [k] = rand () % 9 ;

        for ( j = 0; j < k; j++ )
        {
            if ( row_random [j] == row_random [k]  &&  column_random [j] == column_random [k] )
            {
                row_random [k] = rand () % 9 ;
                column_random [k] = rand () % 9 ;
                j = -1;
            }
        }
    }


    for ( int i = 0; i <= 9; i++ )
    {

        if ( i == 0 )
        {
            for ( i = 1; i <= 27; i++ )
            {
                printf("-");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    for ( int j = 0; j <= 9; j++ )
    {
        if ( j == 0 )
        {
            for ( int i = 1; i <= 9; i++ )
            {
                printf("|");
                printf("\n");
            }

        }
    }






    for ( int i = 0; i < n*n; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < n*n; j++ )
        {
            for ( k = 0; k < number; k++ )
            {
                check = '0';
                if ( j == column_random [k] && i == row_random [k] )
                {
                    check = '1';
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    check = '0';
                }
            }

            if ( check == '1' )
            {
                printf("   ");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("  %d ",(i*n + i/n + j) % (n*n) + 1);
            }

        }
        printf("\n");   
    }



    return 0;
}
```

And here is my execution trace:

```
Enter percentage of empty squares: 50
---------------------------
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
  1      3   4   5      7   8   9
  4   5         8   9      2
     8            3   4   5
  2   3         6   7         1
           8         2      4
           2      4   5      7
  3      5   6               2
        8   9      2      4   5
  9   1   2   3


------------------
(program exited with code: 0)
```

I don't really know how to solve this problem. I figured that adding the space when printing out the numbers should give enough space for printing the edge borders, but it doesn't seem so. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Edit: Thanks everyone for all your help! Though not exactly like the picture, I've come it with something close, and below is my improved code:

```
for ( int i = 0; i <= n*n; i++ )
    {
        if ( i == 9 )
        {
            for ( int x =0; x <= 30; x++)
            {
                printf("-");
            }
            printf("\n");
            break;
        }

        if ( i == 0 || i == 3 || i == 6 )
        {
            for ( int x =0; x <= 30; x++)
            {
                printf("-");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        for ( int j = 0; j < n*n; j++ )
        {
            for ( k = 0; k < number; k++ )
            {
                check = '0';
                if ( j == column_random [k] && i == row_random [k] )
                {
                    check = '1';
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    check = '0';
                }
            }
            if ( check == '1' )
            {
                if ( check == '1' && ( j == 0 || j == 3 || j == 6 ) )
                {
                    printf("|   ");
                }
                else if ( check == '1' && j == 8 )
                {
                    printf("   |");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("   ");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ( j == 0 || j == 3 || j == 6 )
                {
                    printf("|%2d ",(i*n + i/n + j) % (n*n) + 1);
                }
                else if ( check == '0' && j == 8 )
                {
                    printf("%2d |",(i*n + i/n + j) % (n*n) + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%2d ",(i*n + i/n + j) % (n*n) + 1);
                }

            }

        }
        printf("\n");   



}
```

Just an update, and I'll go through all suggested improvements as well!

Comment: Your program will print everything you tell it to print **in the order you tell it**. So if you have a loop that prints `|\n` **before** you even print your board, naturally this is the output you'll get.

Comment: The trick here is to realize that you have to print the whole line at once.  You can't print all the left side, then all the numbers, then the right bars.  Instead, print the top (it never changes) then use `printf` statements to print the rows with numbers.  It should be something like `|%c%c%c|%c%c%c|%c%c%c|` and then feed in the digit as a character if you know it, or a spac if you dont

Comment: Oh, I see. So I just can't print the border lines separately, right?

Comment: You should take a look at libncurses :)

Comment: You can paint borders (and other things, digits included) by moving the cursor in the wanted position before printing. How to do it depends on platform, and Pierre suggestion is good if available. Otherwise, you can print always whole lines, and repaint the whole game every time is needed (perhaps after clearing screen?).

Answer (score 2):

A sudoku board is small enough that you don't even need loops (you could use loops if you want to though):

```
void print_line(int *start) {
   printf("| %d %d %d | %d %d %d | %d %d %d |\n", 
       start[0], start[1], start[2],
       start[3], start[4], start[5],
       start[6], start[7], start[8]);

void print_edge() {
    printf("+-------+-------+-------+\n");
}

print_board(int board[81]) {
    print_edge();
    print_line(board + 0*9);
    print_line(board + 1*9);
    print_line(board + 2*9);
    print_edge();
    print_line(board + 3*9);
    print_line(board + 4*9);
    print_line(board + 5*9);
    print_edge();
    print_line(board + 6*9);
    print_line(board + 7*9);
    print_line(board + 8*9);
    print_edge();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a raster.

Your console screen is probably 80x25 character wide. Find out its dimensions.

Then set up an array char screen[25][80], and write a function to write the entire screen to the console in one go. Get it working, then the Sudoku problem becomes an issue of placing addition signs, vertical pipes and minus signs in the right places.